# What does 0 means in the following typescript code snippets?

Tags: typescript

What does 0 means in the following typescript code snippets?

```
var x = (a: number) => 0;
var y = (b: number, s: string) => 0;
y = x; // OK
x = y; // Error
```

Comment: I don't know what typescript is but I bet this question could be trivially answered by checking the documentation.

Comment: Yep: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#4.11

Answer (score 2):

You're defining an [*arrow function*](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#4.11), `() => 0` is simply a function that returns 0 (the function body doesn't do anything except `return 0`)

Same with `(a: number) => 0` and `(b: number, s: string) => 0`, they're functions that take those parameters and return 0

- `() => 0` transpiles to `function () { return 0; }`
- `(a: number) => 0` transpiles to `function (a) { return 0; }`
- `(b: number, s: string) => 0` transpiles to `function (b, s) { return 0; }`

You can see the Javascript equivalent in this Typescript playground:

http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=var%20f%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%200%0A%0Avar%20x%20%3D%20(a%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%200%3B%0Avar%20y%20%3D%20(b%3A%20number%2C%20s%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%200%3B

<sub>The Playground URL is long because the source code is embedded in the URL</sub>